# PM2 API doesn't connect

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am unable to connect to the PM2 instance through API.

following is the code

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');

console.log('pm2  ', pm2);

pm2.connect(function (err) {
    console.log('pm2 error ', err);
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(2);
    }
    else {
        pm2.list(function (err, res) { });
        var pm2 = require('pm2');

    }
});
```

and the error i get is

```
$ sudo node maintanance/manage-pm2.js 
pm2   undefined
(node:56046) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
pm2 error  null
/home/ubuntu/laks/middleware-2.0/maintanance/manage-pm2.js:12
        pm2.list(function (err, res) { });
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined
    at /home/ubuntu/laks/middleware-2.0/maintanance/manage-pm2.js:12:13
    at /home/ubuntu/laks/middleware-2.0/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:182:16
    at /home/ubuntu/laks/middleware-2.0/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:54:16
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ubuntu/laks/middleware-2.0/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:371:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

Yes, surely, i have installed the "pm2" version ^4.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line `var pm2 = require('pm2');` you are reinitializing pm2 while `pm2.list` is still running

`processList` will give you list of pm2 instances

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');

console.log('pm2  ', pm2);

pm2.connect(function (err) {
    console.log('pm2 error ', err);
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(2);
    }
    else {
        pm2.list(function (err, processList) { 
            console.log(processList);
        });
    }
});
```